# How to test a string returned from a method in xunit test when it so long?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

For the next example `ShowRecipes` should returns a string with these text, it works.

```
[Fact]
public void ReturnsAllRecipesIfTheFileIsntNeitherEmptyNorNull()
{
    ModelData modelData = new(@"..\..\..\..\Recipes.csv");
    modelData.ShowRecipes().Should().Be("1. Blablabla\n2. Blablabla\n3. Blablabla");
}
```

Nevertheless, the document itself has a LOT of recipes inside, the actual value is not that easy due to the file's size. So harcoding it it's kinda hard.

So here's my question, what'd be the best way to test these kind of things?

Another example:

The test check that the lightbulbs are on in `(X,Y)` position.

```
[Fact]
public void AllBulbsAreOnWhenInstructionsAre499_499_500_500()
{
    LightGroup lightGroup = new LightGroup();

    lightGroup.Instruction(
        new Coordinate(499, 499),
        new Coordinate(500, 500)
    );

    lightGroup.At(499, 499).Status().Should().Be(1);
    lightGroup.At(499, 500).Status().Should().Be(1);
    lightGroup.At(500, 499).Status().Should().Be(1);
    lightGroup.At(500, 500).Status().Should().Be(1);
}
```

Notice that this example is simple. Imagine this is a matrix 1000x1000, and I turned on all these lightbulbs, how could I test all these cases without using a loop in the test?

Comment: Unit tests don't interact with the file system. You've got a different type of test if that's the case.

Comment: See this @gunr2171, imagine instead that I have a matrix 1000x1000 and I'd like to test if every position (1000000 in total) has a 1 inside, because that's my test. How could I write this test? Also for this case, what kind of test I need?

Comment: The goal is to test that all lights are switched on, so what is wrong with the loop? Alternative approach to test that all items have same value `.Should().OnlyContain(bulb => bulb.Status == 1)`

Comment: It is totally ok to access immutable files as long as you accept that tests will be little bit slower. Notice that feedback is purpose of the tests regardless of the "type of the test" and tests which use "production" environment provide more useful feedback.

Comment: We can write tests that operate on a small scale. For example, suppose you had code that sorts a list. You would likely test with the smallest list that can prove the sorting works. You wouldn't need to sort 10,000 items.